# React simple select-panel app without external modules

Tags: reactjs

What is the simplest way to create a select-panel in React? I can't seem to find an example without using the react-select module.
The item selected should have a glowing border and a check mark on the top right, like this:

[image]

Comment: You can't find an example, because it's not "that" simple. Especially lacking any precise requirements like: what should be contained within such a select-panel-item - a react node, image, color? The task would require creating bunch of styling, maybe even utilising graphical assets (checkmark svg) and creating a parent component with all the logic. It's not "that' hard as well, but requires some thought and quite a bit of code.

Comment: @Wiktor Bednarz I didn't feel it's necessary to elaborate because the pic is pretty self-explanatory. Whatever can be contained within. I guess I was more asking about the approach to achieve the selecting effect as the check, glowing border, etc.; and the grid layout.